# What encoding is this (in mail source code)?

Tags: php, encoding, escaping

When I look into source of mail I found this type of encoding where "=09" is apparently space... How to make it in PHP?

```
    <style type=3D"text/css">
=09=09body=2C#bodyTable=2C#bodyCell{
=09=09=09height:100% !important;
=09=09=09margin:0;
=09=09=09padding:0;
=09=09=09width:100% !important;
=09=09}
=09=09table{
=09=09=09border-collapse:collapse;
=09=09}
=09=09img=2Ca img{
=09=09=09border:0;
=09=09=09outline:none;
```

Comment: It's actually a horizontal tab character rather than a space: ASCII character `0x09`

Comment: It's quoted-printable. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable

Comment: Isn't there a Content-Encoding header that says what format it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [quoted-printable encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable), using printable ASCII characters to encode 8-bit data.

PHP has [quoted_printable_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.quoted-printable-decode.php) function to decode it.